# DISTINCT clause used on non-distinct select error

Tags: sql, distinct-values, polyhedra

I want to populate a drop down box using the one field from by data, I just want the unique values returned for a set of data from one table.  Group by is not implemented in the polyhedra database I am using.  Name is primary key for table and all names are unique.

I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userstring05
FROM digital
WHERE userstring05 LIKE '_%'
  AND name LIKE '200-B%'
```

But I get this error:

> DISTINCT clause used on non-distinct select

Comment: I believe this was mis-tagged with mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ENEA Polyhedra reference](http://www.spartancontrols.com/~/media/resources/enea/m/enea_polyhedra_sql_reference_manual_june_2006.pdf):

> Inclusion of the **distinct** clause will generate an error if the **select**
>   statement could potentially return duplicate rows. Only **select**
>   statements whose output columns include all the primary key columns of
>   the tables specified in the **from** clause can be successfully executed
>   with a **distinct** clause.

So I guess this DBMS doesn't really implement `distinct`, as this constraint nullifies the interest of using this clause. Unless you join a table without any primary key, maybe ?

EDIT: Seems like this resource is old. Which version of Polyhedra are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use distinct. Use group by to get your result.

```
SELECT userstring05 FROM digital WHERE userstring05 like '_%'
AND name LIKE '200-B%' GROUP BY userstring05
```

This will give you the requested result. I haven't tested it since you are not providing some example data but should be ok

Comment: The database I am working with has limited functions available: I tired your query and this is result "not implemented: select: GROUP BY"

Comment: @user5410577 what DB are you using? Both your query and mine should work in mysql

Comment: Polyhedra Version 8.01.00.04

Comment: @user5410577 then why did you tag it with mysql and sql too?